# ¿Cómo guardar elementos en una lista mediante el uso de un "While"?

Tags: python

Estoy aprendiendo usar Python y me dieron de tarea hacer un programa que guarde una lista de:

- Exámenes
- Fecha de los exámenes
- Tareas y
- fechas de las tareas.

Aquí les dejo el código:

```
pruebas=[]

fechasp=[]

tareas=[]

tareasf=[]

print("Para inicar programa escriba ON")


v1= input("Inserte el codigo para iniciar programa")
if v1== "ON":
    print("El programa se ha iniciado")



while True:
    r2= input("Toque P si quiere modificar la lista de pruebas, toque T si quiere modificar la lista de tareas")
    if r2== "P":
        p1=input("Ingrese para materia de pruebas")
        pruebas.append(p1)
        p2=input("ingrese para fechas")
        fechasp.append(p2)  
        print(pruebas)
        print(fechasp)
    
    if r2== "T":
        t1 = input("Ingrese la materia a la que pertenece la tarea")
        tareas.append(t1)
        t2= input("Ingrese la fecha limite para entregar la tarea")
        tareasf.append(t2)
        print(tareas)
        print(tareasf)
```

Lo que quiero hacer es seguir el código con un INPUT que me diga:

> Toca Z para eleminar elementos de la lista, Toca  S para seguir agregando cosas

Sé como seguir el código si se toca Z, pero no sé cómo seguir el código si  se toca S, (En teoría si toca S debería volver a el INPUT de la variable r2, pero no sé como hacer que haga eso).

¿Me darían una mano con esa parte?

Perdón si no se entiende mi idea.

Comment: Si tienes un `while True` usas `continue` y `break` dependiendo de lo que necesites. No queda del todo claro cuál es problema que tienes, o qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 2):

Bueno mi idea no es hacerte la tarea, mas que nada es ayudarte a mejorar un poco tu código y que aprendas, tampoco quiero asustarte con if anidados, try except, etc. ya que recién estas empezando y adelantarte sin saber lo fundamentos básicos de la programación te puede dificultar un poco, la idea es que vayas paso a paso.

bueno empecemos

lo primero que haremos es solicitar al usuario por teclado que ingrese 'ON' y en el caso de que ingrese otra cosa el programa se termina

cuando el usuario ingresa 'ON' el programa se  empezara a ejecutar linea por linea, declararemos una variable 'opcion_mientras = 0' para cuando llegue al bucle este se pueda ejecutar sin problemas y genere un ciclo que solo se pueda romper si el usuario ingresa 5, usar un while true en algunos casos no es una buena practica ya que te obliga a romper el bucle con un break entre otras cosas.

```
opcion = input("Ingrese 'ON' para iniciar el programa 'OFF' para cerrar el programa: ")

if opcion == "ON":
   print("El programa se ha iniciado")

   opcion_mientras = 0

   while opcion_mientras != 5:
```

cuando el flujo del programa este ejecutando el ciclo while le imprimimos al usuario todas estas opciones una debajo de otra por que '\n' me permite hacer saltos de lineas y es un poco mas elegante que escribir puros 'prints hacia abajo', luego de esto al usuario le solicitaremos que ingrese un opcion por teclado en el caso de que ingrese 1 le permitiremos al usuario ingresar una pruba y su fecha, si la opcion es 2 le permitimos ingresar una tarea y su fecha.

Ok hasta aqui todo bien.

```
   print("Seleccione un opcion\n1 - para agregar una prueba\n2 - para agregar una tarea\n3 - para eliminar un elemento de la lista\n4 - para mostrar las pruebas o tareas\n5 - Salir")

   opcion_mientras = int(input("> "))

   if opcion_mientras == 1:
        print("Selecciono modificar prueba")

        agregar = input("Ingrese el nombre de la materia: ")
        agregar_fecha = input("Ingrese la fecha de la prueba: ")

        pruebas.append(agregar)
        fecha_de_las_pruebas.append(agregar_fecha)

        print("La prueba se agrego con exito...")

    elif opcion_mientras == 2:
        print("Selecciono agregar tarea")

        agregar_tarea = input("Ingrese el nombre de la tarea: ")
        agregar_fecha_tarea = input("Ingrese la fecha limite de la tarea: ")

        tareas.append(agregar_tarea)
        fecha_limite_de_las_tareas.append(agregar_fecha_tarea)
```

Ahora si el usuario ingresa 3 le desplegamos otro menu y que seleccione a la lista en la que desee eliminar algo, ok supongamos selecciono la opcion uno, lo primero que haremos sera crear un variable 'contador = 1' y con un for recorreremos la lista pruebas e imprimiremos cada prueba de la lista, contador lo que hace es asignarle un id a cada prueba entonces cuando se imprima una tendra id 1 la siguiente id 2 y asi sucesivamente, y bueno para eliminar nuevamente le solicitamos al usuario que ingrese un id de la prueba a eliminar, luego procedemos a eliminar ¿como lo hacemos? primero llamamos la lista y mediante un punto y su metodo pop y dentro de parentesis agregamos la variable 'eliminar_prueba - 1' ¿por que -1? por que cada elemento de una lista tiene un indice siendo el indice del primer elemento 0 y asi sucesivamente.

```
        elif opcion_mientras == 3:
        print("Selecciono eliminar elementos de la lista\nSeleccione la lista a la que desea acceder y eleminar un elemento\n1 - Pruebas\n2 - Fecha de las pruebas\n3 - Tareas\n4 - Fecha de las tareas")

        opcion_lista = int(input("> "))

        if opcion_lista == 1:
            print("Seleccione un elemento a eliminar")
            
            contador = 1
            for i in pruebas:
                print(contador,  i)
                contador += 1

            eliminar_prueba = int(input("> "))
            pruebas.pop(eliminar_prueba - 1)
```

bueno con esto ya deberias seguir tu el codigo espero que esto te pueda servir.

Answer (score 1):

cree este script ustedes medieron la idea

```
from pynput import keyboard 
import time

lista = []    
o = 0

while o <= 5:

    def pulsa(tecla):
        lista.append(tecla)         
        time.sleep(1.0)
        print(lista)    

    def suelta(tecla):
        if tecla == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('ctrl'):
            return False  
        
    keyboard.Listener(pulsa, suelta).run()      
    o+=1
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Con una sola respuesta es suficiente. ¿Para qué más?

Answer (score -1):

Quizás esto pueda servirte (aunque puede ser optimizado):

```
pruebas=[]

fechasp=[]

tareas=[]

tareasf=[]

print("Para iniciar programa escriba ON")

v1= input("Inserte el código para iniciar programa: ")
if v1== "ON":
    print("El programa se ha iniciado.")
    print("Si desea salir, marque OFF en lugar de las opciones ofrecidas.")
    salir=False
    while salir is False:
        r2 = input("Toque P si quiere modificar la lista de pruebas, toque T si quiere modificar la lista de tareas: ")
        if r2 == "P":
            while True:
                p1 = input("Ingrese para materia de pruebas: ")
                if p1 == "OFF":
                    salir = True
                    break
                if p1.isspace() or len(p1)==0:
                    print("Debe ingresar una materia de pruebas.")
                else:
                    pruebas.append(p1)
                    break
            if salir:
                break
            while True:
                p1 = input("Ingrese para fechas: ")
                if p1 == "OFF":
                    salir = True
                    break
                if p1.isspace() or len(p1)==0:
                    print("Debe ingresar una fecha.")
                else:
                    fechasp.append(p1)
                    break
            if salir:
                break
            print(pruebas)
            print(fechasp)
            while True:
                r2 = input("Toca Z para eliminar elementos de la lista, Toca S para seguir agregando cosas: ")
                if r2 == "OFF":
                    salir=True
                    break
                if r2 == "S":
                    break
                elif r2 == "Z":
                    if len(pruebas) == 0:
                        print("No quedan pruebas para eliminar.")
                        break
                    while True:
                        r2 = input("Ingrese el número de la prueba a eliminar: ")
                        if r2 == "OFF":
                            salir = True
                            break
                        try:
                            r2=int(r2)
                            if 0 >= r2 or r2 > len(pruebas):
                                print("Esta prueba no existe.")
                            else:
                                del pruebas[r2-1]
                                del fechasp[r2-1]
                                print("La prueba #" + str(r2) + " se ha eliminado con éxito")
                                print(pruebas)
                                print(fechasp)
                                break
                        except:
                            print("Debe introducir un número entero.")
                    if salir:
                        break
                else:
                    print("Debe especificar una opción válida.")
            if salir:
                break
        elif r2 == "T":
            while True:
                p1 = input("Ingrese la materia a la que pertenece la tarea: ")
                if p1 == "OFF":
                    salir = True
                    break
                if p1.isspace() or len(p1)==0:
                    print("Debe ingresar una materia a la que pertenece la tarea.")
                else:
                    tareas.append(p1)
                    break
            if salir:
                break
            while True:
                p1 = input("Ingrese la fecha límite para entregar la tarea: ")
                if p1 == "OFF":
                    salir = True
                    break
                if p1.isspace() or len(p1)==0:
                    print("Debe ingresar una fecha.")
                else:
                    tareasf.append(p1)
                    break
            if salir:
                break
            print(tareas)
            print(tareasf)
            while True:
                r2 = input("Toca Z para eliminar elementos de la lista, Toca S para seguir agregando cosas: ")
                if r2 == "OFF":
                    salir = True
                    break
                if r2 == "S":
                    break
                elif r2 == "Z":
                    if len(tareas) == 0:
                        print("No quedan tareas para eliminar.")
                        break
                    while True:
                        r2 = input("Ingrese el número de la tarea a eliminar: ")
                        if r2 == "OFF":
                            salir = True
                            break
                        try:
                            r2=int(r2)
                            if 0 >= r2 or r2 > len(tareas):
                                print("Esta tarea no existe.")
                            else:
                                del tareas[r2-1]
                                del tareasf[r2-1]
                                print("La tarea #" + str(r2) + " se ha eliminado con éxito")
                                print(tareas)
                                print(tareasf)
                                break
                        except:
                            print("Debe introducir un número entero.")
                    if salir:
                        break                
                else:
                    print("Debe especificar una opción válida.")
            if salir:
                break
        elif r2 == "OFF":
            salir=True
        else:
            print("Debe especificar una opción válida.")
```

Se inicia el programa cuando se teclea “ON” y si se desea parar su ejecución, cuando pida la entrada de algún valor, se teclea “OFF”. Si alguna de las entradas no es válida (no incluye errores en formato de fecha o nombres de materias), se mostrará al usuario un mensaje y luego se le pedirá que ingrese nuevamente el valor requerido. Además, cada vez que se inserte una prueba o tarea, se pide al usuario que escoja si desea eliminar alguna (prueba o tarea según el tipo de lo que se haya insertado) o insertar otros elementos. Para eliminar se pide que ingrese el número correspondiente a la prueba o tarea (no la posición), si no es válido (porque no es un entero o se pasa de los límites del arreglo), se vuelve a pedir que ingrese el número, repitiendo el proceso.  Si se escoge eliminar elementos a un arreglo vacío, se muestra un mensaje que lo indique y se vuelve a mostrar la opción inicial. Por cada “error” al validar la entrada, se dará la oportunidad al usuario de corregirlo y volver a realizar el subproceso deseado. En el caso de eliminar, se continuará mostrando la opción, hasta que no haya elementos en el arreglo o el usuario decida que quiere ingresar otros elementos. El usuario podrá mantener un mejor control (no óptimo) de la ejecución del programa.

Comment: ¿Qué hace este código?